# Solving an ODE $\psi''(x) + \left[a^2 - x^{2n}\right]\psi(x) = 0$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, quantum-mechanics

Consider an ODE
$$
\psi''(x) + \left[a^2 - x^{2n}\right]\psi(x) = 0
$$
for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. The problem originally came from QM and is about finding energy levels in a given potential, so I'm looking for regular solutions (and specific $a$'s which correspond to them) which vanish at $x = \pm \infty$.

So far I've attempted a substitution $\psi = \exp\left(-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) u(x)$ which leads to

$$
u''(x) - 2x^n u'(x) + [a^2-nx^{n-1}] u(x)=0
$$

then I used $x^{n+1} = t$ and got to

$$
(n+1)^2t^2u'' +\bigl[(n+1)nt-2(n+1)t^2\bigr]u' + \bigl[a^2 t^{\frac{2}{n+1}} - n t\bigr]u = 0 
$$

Which is "almost nice" apart from the non-integer power in the $a^2$ term. I do not have an idea how can I proceed further.

Another approach I've tried factorizing the initial differential operator

$$
\hat{H} = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x^{2n} = A^*A + \epsilon
$$

with

$$
A = \frac{d}{dx} + \beta(x),\;\; A^* = -\frac{d}{dx} + \beta(x)
$$

But here I'm stuck at Riccati which looks like

$$
-\beta'(x) + \beta(x)^2 = x^{2n} - \epsilon
$$

I've tried a finite-degree polynomial, but it seems that there is no such solution for $\beta$ when $n>1$.

Finally, I've tried using Wolfram Mathematica to solve the initial equation, but it seems to be stuck after the $n=4$ (in cases of $n=2, 3$ it produces solutions in terms of Heun functions which I am unfamiliar with).

Comment: Your options are: 1. Rewrite the differential equation in the form of a known equation (parabolic cylinder, Bessel, etc). 2. Power series solution (ie. Frobenius' method). 3. Perturbation theory. Since Mathematica does not solve the equation, option 1 is not likely to be fruitful.

Your factorization shows the very general connection between Riccati equations and second order linear differential equations.

Is there any reason to believe the arbitrary $n$ case should have a 'nice' solution?

Comment: The problem was initially stated with the potential having a "strength" parameter $U_0$, however, nothing was specified about its relation to other parameters so I expect that at least the $a^2$ should have some adequate closed form. I haven't attempted perturbation theory yet, maybe it's one of the cases when one of its orders will accidentally spit out an exact solution.

Comment: What is the context of the problem? It is only for very special potentials that we can find exact solutions, so *expecting* to find a closed form/ exact solution for (essentially) arbitrary potentials is a bit optimistic.  In case it helps: I think that asymptotically, as $x \to \infty$ (and $n>1$), $\psi(x) \sim x^{-n/2}\exp\left( \pm \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$. So one way to break into the problem is to use the ansatz $\psi(x)=x^{-n/2}\exp\left( \pm \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)g(x)$, then attempt to solve the resulting equation for $g(x)$ using a power series

Comment: It is one of the sample problems I've been given for the landau theoretical minimum exam preparation. The precise text is the following:

"Find energy levels for one-dimensional potential $U = U_0 \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2n}$. "

I've completed plenty of sample problems for this exam and I am certain that the exact solution is expected unless parameter relation is specified.

Well, now I have several ideas to check. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! I'd *guess* that the intent was to use WKB to find the approximate energies, but I would be very pleased if someone were to disprove this hypothesis and post the exact solution

Comment: After some Googling, and playing around with various series solutions, I am convinced the question intended you to find the approximate energies (and that an exact solution, even in terms of special functions, is not likely). Even this is not easy in an exam setting as it requires one to identify the integral form of the beta function. In the end we get the energies $a_m^2 \sim \left[(m+\frac{1}{2}) \sqrt{\pi} \frac{\Gamma((2n)^{-1}+3/2)}{\Gamma((2n)^{-1}+1)}  \right]^{2n/(n+1)}$, $m \to \infty$

Comment: After speaking with some people who have participated in this exam from both sides, I've been also told that the intent is to find approximate levels so there isn't much else to do. My WKB result for energy levels seems to be the same so thanks for providing independent calculations.